# how to merge multiple list in one dict in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Example = I have one dict like this

```
{10: [10, 12, 13], 11: [11], 12: [14,15],15:[16]}
```

i want this type of output

```
{10: [12:[14,15:[16]], 13],11:[]}
```

Comment: Your desired output is not valid Python.

Comment: Congratulations, your question received my 200th edit! YAY!!!
As for the actual question, please explain why you want that kind of output. Is it based on some kind of filter or what?

Comment: Possibly you mean nested dictionaries, isn't?

Comment: I don't understand your output.  It looks like you want to combine things to eliminate duplicates, but that doesn't explain why "11:[11]" survives.  If you eliminated "10" from the "10" list, then it should be "11:[]".  Right?

Comment: yes i want nested dictionary

Comment: sorry its my output mistake there is output like this 11:[ ]

Comment: @GauravSolanki Still, the output doesn't make much sense... `[14,15:[16]]` is wrongly formatted whether it's a dictionary or a list.

Comment: Is this some kind of tree-traversal representation?

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for your exampled input.
I'm not sure if it works for other inputs.
Also, maybe it's not the best implemented program.
But I hope it helps.

```
input = {10: [10, 12, 13], 11: [11], 12: [14, 15], 15: [16]}
# {10: [12:[14,15:[16]], 13],11:[]}
key_not_checked = {n: True for n in input}
output = {}


def check_elemnt_inlist(element):
    value = input.get(element, None)
    if not value:
        return element
    elif len(value) == 1:
        key_not_checked[element] = False
        return {element: value}
    else:
        nested = {}
        val = []
        for i in value:
            if int(i) != int(element):
                val.append(check_elemnt_inlist(i))
        nested[element] = val
        key_not_checked[element] = False
        return nested


for key in input:
    top_value = input[key]
    c = []
    if key_not_checked[key]:
        for g in top_value:
            if int(g) != int(key):
                c.append(check_elemnt_inlist(g))
        output[key] = c
    key_not_checked[key] = False

print(output)
```

The output will be like this:

`{10: [{12: [14, {15: [16]}]}, 13], 11: []}`